# ReferenceError: Email is not defined (smtp.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, referenceerror

I am getting undefined function errors when calling an external script (smpt.js) for use on a Vue project I am working on. The error states "ReferenceError: Email is not defined." Any help appreciated.

```
<script>
export default {
methods: {
 sendEmail() {
  Email.send({
    Host : 'smtp.gmail.com',
    Username : '@gmail.com',
    Password : "password",
     To : '@gmail.com',
    From : '@gmail.com',
    Subject : "This is the subject",
    Body : "And this is the body"
    }).then(message => alert(message));
  },
  mounted() {
   let externalScript = document.createElement('script');
   externalScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js');
   document.head.appendChild(externalScript)
 }
}}
</script>
```

Comment: How is the sendEmail method called?

Comment: I'm calling it on a contact form via @submit.prevent="sendEmail".

Comment: I had a similar issue recently. Can you confirm smtp.js is requested and returned as expected? Check the network tab.

Comment: I do see an smtp.js line in the network tab. Status code is 200.

Comment: Hmm. I’m thinking the script hasn’t loaded successfully at the time you’re triggering the sendEmail method, but I’d expect it to be ready if you’re seeing it in the network tab and no errors in the console. Add ```console.log(typeof window.Email)``` to the beginning of sendEmail, is it undefined?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I can see the smtp.js loaded successfully. Anyone?